Python modules inside subdirectories not found
I'm using Python 3.12.5 and my directory structure is as follows:
project/
 --> subproject/
      --> scripts/
           --> script.py
      --> utils/
           --> __init__.py
           --> utility.py

The utility.py script contains a class, and I am trying to call that class within the script.py script.
No variation seems to be working... for instance, the following __init__.py still does not enable my script.py script to recognize the utility:
from . import utility
from .utility import *

The import in script.py is then for instance:
from utils.utility import *

The error is always ModuleNotFoundError.
I would prefer to do this without sys.path appends, setup.py library instantiations or pip3 module imports.

This question is similar to: Import a file from a subdirectory?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Sorceri if I knew how it was different I would probably have an answer—the accepted solution on that question, which I reviewed prior to posting my question, does not seem to work, or be relevant, since I already have an __init__.py file in my module subdirectory utils/. So I'm not sure what the issue is.
